# Program runs very slow on a Oracle database server of Linux 64-bit

Tags: linux, oracle

I have a program which takes in average 30 minutes to run on general 64-bit Linux machines. But it takes 150 minutes to run on a 64-bit Linux machine where a Oracle database running.

vmstat shows the program need in average 6GB memory and bi=0 on general machines. But it uses no more than 2GB memory on Oracle database server and bi is very high.

The Oracle database server has total memory=500G, SGA=42112M and PGA=20G.

My question is what Oracle setup would restrict memory usage of other program.

The following is a little part of the top output when the program is running:

```
top - 15:34:08 up 114 days, 12:27, 11 users,  load average: 0.48, 0.60, 0.54
Tasks: 872 total,   2 running, 870 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 15.8%us,  3.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 64.6%id, 16.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  529409524k total, 523431316k used,  5978208k free,   788964k buffers
Swap: 20971516k total,   247040k used, 20724476k free, 234761252k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                         
49096 oracle    20   0 41.5g 1.1g 1.0g S 47.5  0.2   0:14.90 oracle                                                          
17862 oracle    20   0 41.5g  46m  32m R 18.3  0.0   5:09.58 oracle                                                          
17874 oracle    20   0 41.5g  47m  31m S 16.5  0.0   4:50.99 oracle                                                          
35934 root      RT   0  769m 101m  55m S 12.8  0.0   5830:15 osysmond.bin                                                    
17864 oracle    20   0 41.5g  46m  31m S 11.0  0.0   4:53.54 oracle                                                          
17882 oracle    20   0 41.5g  46m  31m S  7.3  0.0   5:20.39 oracle                                                          
52363 applmgr   20   0 15636 1760  828 R  7.3  0.0   0:00.08 top                                                             
35064 root      20   0 1974m  47m  14m S  3.7  0.0 642:05.39 ohasd.bin                                                       
26123 oracle    20   0 33.4g  33m  16m S  1.8  0.0  74:18.77 oracle                                                          
27764 oracle    20   0 33.4g  21m  19m S  1.8  0.0   0:41.09 oracle                                                          
36387 root      20   0  814m  20m  10m S  1.8  0.0 384:21.37 octssd.bin                                                      
38011 oracle    -2   0 1237m  14m  12m S  1.8  0.0   1212:52 oracle                                                          
38130 root      20   0 2910m  60m  20m S  1.8  0.0   1070:16 crsd.bin                                                        
38192 oracle    20   0 1239m  17m  15m S  1.8  0.0  21:21.70 oracle                                                          
39657 root      20   0 1582m  23m  11m S  1.8  0.0   1108:05 orarootagent.bi                                                 
41587 oracle    20   0 33.4g  23m  20m S  1.8  0.0   0:00.14 oracle                                                          
49809 oracle    20   0 41.4g  57m  54m S  1.8  0.0   0:00.73 oracle                                                          
1 root      20   0 21460 1564 1240 S  0.0  0.0  44:37.17 init                                                            
2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:05.13 kthreadd                                                        
3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  18:12.77 ksoftirqd/0                                                     
6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 163191:59 migration/0                                                     
7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:50.35 watchdog/0                                                      
8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 164526:35 migration/1                                                     
10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  18:48.93 ksoftirqd/1                                                     
12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:51.10 watchdog/1                                                      
13 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 161719:04 migration/2                                                     
15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   8:58.82 ksoftirqd/2                                                     
16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:00.06 watchdog/2                                                      
17 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 162585:32 migration/3                                                     
19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   6:18.01 ksoftirqd/3                                                     
20 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:38.44 watchdog/3                                                      
21 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 158088:12 migration/4                                                     
23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  12:46.60 ksoftirqd/4                                                     
24 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:44.32 watchdog/4                                                      
25 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 164162:22 migration/5                                                     
27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  14:00.94 ksoftirqd/5                                                     
28 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:39.26 watchdog/5                                                      
29 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 162112:29 migration/6                                                     
31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   7:36.89 ksoftirqd/6                                                     
32 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:36.18 watchdog/6                                                      
33 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 160716:53 migration/7                                                     
35 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   3:33.29 ksoftirqd/7                                                     
36 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:32.82 watchdog/7                                                      
37 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset                                                          
38 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                         
39 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                           
40 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:38.28 sync_supers                                                     
41 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:06.53 bdi-default                                                     
42 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                     
43 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                         
44 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                         
45 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khubd                                                           
46 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                              
50 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:30.08 khungtaskd                                                      
51 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  13:30.48 kswapd0                                                         
52 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                            
53 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 fsnotify_mark                                                   
54 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto                                                          
60 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                                        
62 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused                                                       
349 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0                                                       
351 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:14.72 hpsa                                                            
364 oracle    20   0 33.4g  37m  31m S  0.0  0.0   0:14.78 oracle                                                          
366 oracle    20   0 33.4g  34m  28m S  0.0  0.0   0:04.32 oracle                                                          
374 oracle    20   0 33.4g  37m  30m S  0.0  0.0   0:05.47 oracle                                                          
377 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 scsi_eh_1                                                       
378 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 scsi_eh_2                                                       
402 root      20   0  102m 4024 3052 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.26 sshd                                                            
484 root      20   0 36268 1340 1048 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.44 vncconfig                                                       
485 root      20   0  150m 3916 2220 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.75 xterm                                                           
486 root      20   0  127m 2184 1484 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.52 twm                                                             
493 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_3                                                       
494 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.76 usb-storage                                                     
497 root      20   0  107m 1860 1460 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 bash                                                            
537 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
539 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
558 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.83 jbd2/dm-1-8                                                     
559 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit                                                 
633 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:15.35 kworker/3:0                                                     
665 root      16  -4 17568 7752  460 S  0.0  0.0  22631:49 udevd                                                           
673 oracle    20   0  102m 2004 1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 sshd                                                            
697 oracle    20   0  108m 2048 1444 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 bash                                                            
771 oracle    20   0 33.4g  25m  21m S  0.0  0.0   0:30.99 oracle                                                          
792 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_4                                                       
1017 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qla2xxx_4_dpc                                                   
1018 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_wq_4                                                       
1021 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_5                                                       
1037 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qla2xxx_5_dpc                                                   
1038 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_wq_5                                                       
1075 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qlcnic                                                          
1135 hpsmh     20   0  176m  11m 4380 S  0.0  0.0   0:25.39 hpsmhd                                                          
1677 oracle    20   0 41.4g 118m 113m S  0.0  0.0   0:01.45 oracle                                                          
1798 oracle    20   0 41.4g  56m  51m S  0.0  0.0   0:00.59 oracle                                                          
1974 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 flush-252:109                                                   
1987 root      20   0  102m 4060 3092 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 sshd                                                            
1993 sysmon    20   0  102m 2004 1036 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.78 sshd                                                            
1994 sysmon    20   0  105m 1888 1440 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.73 bash                                                            
2084 root      20   0  158m 4072 2592 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 sudo                                                            
2110 root      20   0  107m 1580 1236 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 sh                                                              
2488 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd                                                         
2489 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpath_handlerd                                                 
2606 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2612 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2616 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2620 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2624 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2628 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2635 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2638 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2645 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2652 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2658 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2662 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2667 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2672 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2676 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2683 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2686 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2687 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2692 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2699 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2708 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2715 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2718 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2720 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2728 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2734 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2743 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2750 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2753 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2755 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2761 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2766 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2774 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2777 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2782 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2784 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2787 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2790 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2801 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2812 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2814 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2820 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2823 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2827 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2833 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2837 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2842 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2848 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2854 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2864 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2877 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2888 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2901 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2905 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2912 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2920 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2922 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2931 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2940 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2952 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2953 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2955 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2972 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2977 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2983 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2989 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2990 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
2996 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3003 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3010 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3014 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3021 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3027 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3033 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3046 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3053 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3064 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3072 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3092 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3097 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3108 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3114 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3119 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3126 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3133 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3139 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3148 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3153 oracle    20   0 4560m 304m  12m S  0.0  0.1 157:16.04 java                                                            
3154 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3162 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3397 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3399 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3427 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3491 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3492 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3494 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3496 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3499 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3502 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3506 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3511 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3520 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3523 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3529 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush                                                        
3613 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kjournald
```

Comment: how much memory does the server have?

Comment: The top shows it has total 505G and 5G is free.

Comment: try doing a "top -c" it may give a an idea as to what oracle is actually doing. Also with 500gb of memory and only 62gb assigned to oracle (42sga+20pga), with only 5gb free it makes me wonder what else is going on with the server.

Answer (score 0):

We have not enough information to determine what is happening in your server. But the only ways I know that Oracle setup can affect a process behavior (without considering ram/cpu/disk overload) are:

- ulimit: Oracle setup uses this command to limit the maximum number of open file descriptors and to limit the maximum number of process per user.  This command also can be used to limit the max amount of resident memory per process, but Oracle does not use in this way.
- kernel shared memory limit: Oracle setup defines shmmax and shmall and these parameters limit the size of shared memory available in your linux kernel.

But these limits only affects the memory consumption of your program if:

- it is working with too many opened files simultaneously (then it could be affected by ulimit)
- it is spawning processes (to perform some parallel tasks) (then it could be also affected by ulimit)
- it is allocating and using shared memory (the same that Oracle uses for its SGA) (then it could be affected by shmmax and shmall).

There are other linux kernel parameters, process and services that can affect the maximum size of memory resident available for a process (the most popular ones are: via limits.conf, via upstart and via cgroup – see https://afrobeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/linux-limiting-resident-memory/). Those ways are not derived from Oracle setup, but they are derived from kernel configuration.  You must check them.

Note: to determine if it is a limit in RAM usage derived from kernel configuration you can create a program (using Java, C, C++ or any language you want) that reserves and use 6G (e.g. creating arrays of arrays and setting their values) and test if it can use more than 2G.

To determine if Oracle workload interferes with your program you can try to test your program in the Oracle server but with the database instance down (if it is possible).